# Simple search using two categories

Tags: entries, search

I have a venue search tool which has two categories - event type and event size. How do I create an entries loop that returns entries that have both categories assigned?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [relatedTo](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) method and pass an array using the `and` parameter.

```
 {% set venueEventType = craft.request.getParam('catVenueEventType') %}
 {% set venueEventSize = craft.request.getParam('catVenueEventSize') %}

 {% set entries = craft.entries.section('venues').relatedTo(['and', venueEventType, venueEventSize]) %}
```